# Read the rows of a pageblocktable after edit

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using a table in my visualforce page where one of the columns contains an editable field. The field I am using here is of a wrapper class and the editable column is Apex:Inputtext. 
Can anyone tell me how I  can get the rows of the table with the edited text?

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing? Also posting your code will help get you better response.